# Инверсия синей компоненты картинки

Tags: php, изображения

Дорогие знатоки! Хотелось бы узнать способ/метод достижения данной задачи. Интересует именно обработка в PHP.

Заранее спасибо.

PS. Пробовал с помощью GD2. Увы не выходит.

Answer (score 2):

Можно с помощью [ImageMagic](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.imagick.php)

- [separate](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/imagick.separateimagechannel.php)
- [negate](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/imagick.negateimage.php)
- [combine](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/imagick.combineimages.php) тут есть пример разделения на RGB и соединения обратно.

по идее вот этот код должен работать:

```
<?php
$im = new Imagick ("test.jpg");
$red = clone $im;
$red->separateImageChannel (imagick::CHANNEL_RED);
$green = clone $im;
$green->separateImageChannel (imagick::CHANNEL_GREEN);
$red->addImage ($green);
$green->destroy ();
$blue = clone $im;
$blue->separateImageChannel (imagick::CHANNEL_BLUE);
$blue->negateImage();
$red->addImage ($blue);
$blue->destroy();
$red->setFirstIterator ();
$im_new = $red->combineImages (imagick::CHANNEL_ALL);
$im_new->writeImage ("test_rebuilt.png");
echo "<img src=\"test_b_inverted.png\">\r\n";
```

Ещё попробуйте так (из доки по negate вроде-бы следует, но в командной строке через `convert` у меня не получилось):

```
$im = new Imagick ("test.jpg");
$im->negateImage(false,Imagick::CHANNEL_BLUE);
$im->writeImage ("test_b_inverted.png");
```

---

последний пример работает, оставляю первый как пример работы с разложением на слои.

судя по [этому](http://www.roseindia.net/tutorial/php/phpgd/About-negate.html) листингу, в GD тоже можно инвертировать только один канал. но это явно очень медленный способ.

Comment: Первый Пример может быть и работает, но на моем хостинге нет доступа для установки расширения(

И даже второй Не работает. Поддержка GD по умолчанию есть. Но вот же засада, даже стандартный фильтр не работает.

Comment: меняйте хостинг, ответ то тут при чем.